# Trouble with dates in php

Tags: php, html, date

I want to print the date every three months before one year past,from the date selected by user, but when i made the increment the loop breaks and only prints the fist date, could help me, please

this is my code in PHP

```
$fecha = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($_POST['fecha']));
printf( date('d/m/Y',strtotime($fecha)).'----');
$fin = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($fecha."+ 1 year"));
printf(date('d/m/Y',strtotime($fin)).'----');
if($fecha<$fin){
    $fecha = date('m/d/Y',strtotime($fecha."+ 1 month"));
    printf( date('d/m/Y',strtotime($fecha)));
}
<form method="POST" action="./fechas.php">
<input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha">
<input type="submit" value="enviar">
</form>
```

This is the output:

[image]

And i want to print this:

> 15/10/2020----
> 15/11/2020----
> 15/12/2020---
> ...

Comment: You want to print the date for the last 3 months of every year? If the user can select the date that won't work because let's say they start on the 31st of October, November only has 30 days.

Comment: no, i want to print that especific day every X months, for example if i choose september 15, 2020, i want to print: december 15,2020, march 15, 2020, june 15,2020 and finally september 15, 2020.

Answer (score 0):

You're repeatedly reformatting and reparsing dates and intervals with the most unreliable functions when there's an entire [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) library to make your life easier.

```php
$input = new DateTime('2020-09-24', new DatetimeZone('UTC'));
$past = (clone $input)->sub(new DateInterval('P1Y'));
$period = new DateInterval('P3M');

$cur = clone $past;
do {
    echo $cur->format('Y-m-d') . "\n";
    $cur->add($period);
} while( $cur <= $input );
```

Output:

```
2019-09-24
2019-12-24
2020-03-24
2020-06-24
2020-09-24
```